# Materialized view that refresh every 15 minutes without full scan

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following materialized view that needs to be fixed:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW T_MV
REFRESH COMPLETE START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (SYSDATE+15/1440) WITH ROWID
AS SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ * FROM T;
```

The issue is that table T is pretty big and update T_MV creates extra load to the system.
Also table T stores only data for the last 30 days, meanwhile T_MV needs to store all historical data.

Comment: Have you created a materialized view log for table T? If not, then you should, for that will help to avoid fullscan of the table. Then, to refresh every 15 minutes create a dbms_scheduler job calling dbms_mview.refrsh('T','F'). Still, if you need to store historical data, you must have another table besides the materialized view, which will contain data older tan 30 days. And that table should be partitioned by range date.

Comment: In addition to creating an MV Log, you would also need to redefine your MV as `FAST REFRESH` or `FORCE REFRESH`.

Comment: Ditto, you don't want to use materialized views for archiving data like this. They are meant only to improve performance of expensive report-style queries by storing a query result or something intermediate so at user query time less work needs to be done. They are intended to be strictly secondary objects that can always be recreated from their source(s). If you try to store historical data in it that is removing from the primary table, it is no longer secondary but the only source of that data, and that's not safe.

Comment: Thank you all for comments and suggestions. Materialized view was requested by client, because of connection limit of 5 active users at the time according to license agreement. That's why materialized view will be utilized almost like source table. Storing historical data is an additional request from client.

Comment: You have to be careful about the "implementation" requested by the client. What you should focus on is addressing the business needs. *You* should then chose the most a appropriate implementation. As @PaulW says above; this implementation is flawed.